# Display custom posts in checkbox list

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, array

I am working in a WordPress backend design and I would like to know if is there any function like wp_categories_checklist but for posts.

I have an issue here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/order-posts-by-custom-post-type-in-dropdown-field?replies=10 in order to find a multiple selection of my dropdown. So if is there any way to put my posts array in a meta box like the custom categories from WordPress that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Your question seems to have been answered at wordpress.org/support What wasn't answered in that thread? Post all the relevant information here please.

Comment: Hi s_ha_dum. I've not solved the problem yet. When I get the right code I'll put the answer here :)

Comment: So, again, post all the relevant information here please. And explain what isn't solved by that support thread. As is, this is not much of a question, which I'd guess is why there hasn't been much of a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{// post_list  
case 'post_list_produktkrav': 

$items = get_posts( array (  
                                'post_type' => $field['post_type'],  
                                'posts_per_page' => -1  
)); 
foreach($items as $item) {
echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$item->ID.'" name="'.$field_related['id'].'[]" id="'.$item->ID.'"',$meta_related && in_array($item->ID, $meta_related) ? ' checked="checked"' : '',' />  
<label for="'.$item->ID.'">'.$item->post_title.'</label><br />';  
} // end foreach

break;}
```

Comment: By adding this I can display a list of checkboxes and choose one or more.

Comment: Whatever this is – it is not an answer. Please improve this fragment. [answer] Thank you.

Comment: I can't put all the code here because is too long. Maybe a pastebin link it's enough: [link]http://pastebin.com/mW3ZssJ9 :)

Comment: Add an **explanation** to your answer. **Why** does it solve the problem? No need to post more long code blocks.